# Is Xamarin.UITest able to install IPA files to physical iPhones?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.uitest

We've got .ipa files that install manually using iTunes on local iPhones, as well as .apk files that install automatically through Xamarin.UITest using

```
IApp ApplicationContext = ConfigureApp
                    .Android
                    .ApkFile("my/path/to/apk/file")
                    .StartApp();
```

When trying

```
IApp ApplicationContext = ConfigureApp
                    .iOS
                    .DeviceIdentifier("device id string as shown in xcode device list")
                    .AppBundleZip("my/path/to/ipa/file")
                    .StartApp();
```

the .ipa file is unzipped but the response is

> error: Zip file didn't contain a valid app bundle.

**Update**
Using both .InstalledApp and .App("App bundle identifier") like this:

```
IApp ApplicationContext = ConfigureApp
                    .iOS
                    .DeviceIdentifier("device id string as shown in xcode device list")
                    .AppBundleZip("my/path/to/ipa/file")
                    .InstalledApp("app.bundle.id")
                    .StartApp();
```

I get an exception:

> TestError: System.Exception: Can't have both installed app and app bundle.
> at Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.iOSAppConfiguration.Verify()

**Update 2**

Using

```
IApp ApplicationContext = ConfigureApp
                    .iOS
                    .DeviceIdentifier("device id string as shown in xcode device list")
                    .InstalledApp("app.bundle.id")
                    .StartApp();
```

requires the app to be installed already.

Using

```
IApp ApplicationContext = ConfigureApp
                    .iOS
                    .DeviceIdentifier("device id string as shown in xcode device list")
                    .InstalledApp("/my/path/to/ipa/file")
                    .StartApp();
```

only installs the DeviceAgent-Runner.app, not the provided ipa.

Manually unpacking the .ipa and using the .app folder like this:

```
IApp ApplicationContext = ConfigureApp
                    .iOS
                    .DeviceIdentifier("device id string as shown in xcode device list")
                    .AppBundle("/my/path/to/x.app/")
                    .StartApp();
```

results in:

> -> error: This app bundle is not valid for running on physical device. To fix this issue please ensure that your target device is a simulator.

But I can take the x.app and install it on the phone by dragging it into the Installed Apps section of Devices in XCode, so the x.app works on physical devices.

**What is the requirements for installing .ipa files to local physical iPhones through Xamarin.UITest?**

IPA files are signed with an internal enterprise certificate and the Apple ID of the tester is listed in the provisioning profile on the app.
Calabash is tested running on the app using simulator builds (.app bundles), that install perfectly through Xamarin.UITest on iPhone simulators running iOS 12-14 and Xamarin.UITest 3.0.9.

If you have any suggestions for automated (un)installation on physical iPhones, that does not use Xamarin.UITest, I'd be interested in that as a backup plan.

Comment: Can you please add the `.InstalledApp(appBundleName)` and try again?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT was this the update you expected?

Comment: Yes, then remove the AppBundleZip("my/path/to/ipa/file").

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT When the app isn't installed on the phone, using .InstalledApp(bundleId) will fail after DeviceAgent is installed, since the app isn't on the phone. If using .InstalledApp("my/path/to/ipa/file"), it also fails with same error: "Failed to launch application with bundle identifier: my/path/to/ipa/file after 13 tries. Is the app installed?". InstalledApp() can't be used to load an ipa file onto the phone.

Comment: Well, if you want to run on a real device, you should use [installedapp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.uitest.configuration.iosappconfigurator.installedapp?view=xamarin-uitest-sdk). See the document.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT  We are using InstalledApp(), but so far have to manually install the app on the phone before running InstalledApp(). Do you know of a way for Xamarin.UITest to install the app programmatically?

Comment: Don't know a way  for Xamarin.UITest to install the app programmatically. If you are using AppCenter, you can upload app through [command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/frameworks/uitest/ios/upload).

Comment: Put that in as a feature request. We're using accessories that limit use of cloud environments.

Comment: You can open an issue in github for further information, if there is no such a way to  install the app programmatically, you can raise a feature request.